# visualization tree for KNN results, in R

Tags: r, knn

I build classification predictive model using KNN -method, cause another methods worked not well, but this gave the optimal result.

```
acc1=read.xlsx("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ido.xlsx")\

acc1$f2<-NULL
acc1$f3<-NULL
table(factor(na.omit(acc1)$id), 
      FNN::knn.cv(train=prcomp(na.omit(acc1[, -c(1,2)]))$x[, 1], cl=factor(na.omit(acc1)$id), k=1))
```

but, i must give back this model for programmer to coding it to our CRM. Because
KNN doesn't have the equation for predicative model, we decide only based on data , and i want draw the tree plot where clear see, what the desicion we must take(1 or 0).
How do this?
what package is correct for this purpose?

Data is here: [dat](http://www.sendspace.com/file/tuwblk)

Answer (score 1):

KNN looks at the K-nearest neighbours to a point and predicts its value based on those neighbours.

To get the predicted value at some unknown point you find the K nearest neighbours and take the majority or choose randomly in the case of a tie.

There's no "tree plot" in the same way a decision tree algorithm work, except in the sense that nearest neighbours divide the vector space of the data into voronoi polytopes, and, at least for k=1, each voronoi polytope has the predicted value for all points within it. The "tree plot" is then a series of decisions on the result of testing which side of a hyperplane your data point sits.

In 1D the voronoi polytopes are line segments.

Example, 1-NN, in 1 dimension:

```
Data:    ---1--------0--0----1----1-----1--1--0---
Predict: 11111111000000000011111111111111111100000
```

See how the prediction values correspond to the nearest data point on the line above? That's what 1-NN does. You've thrown in an extra principal components step (which is pointless for 1D) as well.

So to predict for a given value, find its nearest neighbours. Use `get.knnx`.

Comment: I did it, but got the error !`> query<- as.matrix(acc1)
> get.knnx(acc1,query, k=1)
Error in get.knnx(acc1, query, k = 1) : Data include NAs` What's wrong? my data can't have NA na.omit(acc1)